# How can I read data from a file into an existing NSData object?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Using `NSFileHandle`, I'm able to read the contents of a file into an `NSData` object like so:

```
NSFileHandle *readHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:filePath];
NSData *data = [readHandle readDataToEndOfFile];
```

The problem is that this code creates a new `NSData` object each time. My app is reading multiple large files in succession; each file is exactly the same size, so I want to avoid the performance hit of creating a new block of memory (the `NSData`) on reading each file, by instead just having a single `NSData` object into which each file is read successively. But I can't find any file-reading method that takes a void pointer to write the contents of the file into.

Is there some other class in iOS besides `NSFileHandle` that can do this?

Aha, `NSInputStream` is what I'm looking for.

Comment: What makes you think that allocation the memory for a new `NSData` object is a performance issue?

Comment: @zaph: my app has to do this 60 times per second. iOS can actually handle this without too much trouble, *except* that it occasionally causes `CADisplayLink` callbacks to be missed, which messes up the animation I'm driving at the same time.

Comment: That did not answer the question.

Comment: @zaph: sure it did. I described the specific "performance problem" that my app is having.

Comment: OK, the question again: What makes you think that allocation the memory for a new NSData object is a performance issue?

Comment: Don't sweat it, I've fixed the problem with NSInputStream. I'd delete this question but apparently that's not possible any more.

Comment: But just for fun: my app has to do this 60 times per second. iOS can actually handle this without too much trouble, except that it occasionally causes CADisplayLink callbacks to be missed, which messes up the animation I'm driving at the same time.

Comment: Still no answer so I assume you are just guessing. BTW, the reason the question can not be deleted is because it has an answer.

Comment: Every iPhone can create a few million NSData objects per second. Takes no time at all. Reading the data takes time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use NSMutableData:

```
[data setData:[readHandle readDataToEndOfFile]];
```

Comment: That won't do it, `readDataToEndOfFile` still creates a new `NSData` and then uses it to overwrite.

Comment: Yeah, but will live just to overwrite the old variable and that's it.