# Specify file offset when creating NSData with contentsOfFile arguments

Tags: swift, nsdata, nsurlsession

I am trying to implement a file uploader using NSURLSession.

The file to be uploaded is specified as:

```
var data: NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path)
```

Suppose, the upload fails for some reason & assuming that I can get an offset to resume upload from.

Is it possible to specify in NSData that we have to start from a given offset (something like do a seek before doing the upload)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a class named `NSFileHandle`. Personally I never used it but it seems like it does what you need. It has `seekToFileOffset` method and `availableData` property so I think you can try it

Comment: thanks... There seems to be a way to get NSData object out of a NSFileHandle as follows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30586289/how-can-i-read-data-from-a-file-into-an-existing-nsdata-object. In the link given, is there any chance of out of memory?

Comment: There is _always_ a chance of out of memory. It'll depend on what position you seek to and how much data remains in the file.

Comment: My files are around 5 MB. Does it not read the data in file buffer by buffer as in a stream, instead of reading until the end of the file?

Comment: looks like that is the only way... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46075793/how-to-get-data-chunks-of-large-video-file-from-avurlasset-using-nsfilehandle. maybe, need to create files of small size.